# Angular 7: some confusion/strange behavior when using loadChildren in routing

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-load-children

I'm using loadChlidren in application, but I have some confusion/strange behavior that I didn't understand why happend.

I have this `app-routing-module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: InformationPageComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'INFO',
      preTitle: 'VISUALIZZA_MODELLO'
    },
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './visualizza-modello/modello.module#ModelloModule',
    canActivateChild: []
  }, 
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent//HomeComponent
  }
];
```

And in modello-routing-module.ts I have :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'visualizza-modello',
        data: {
          title: 'DELEGHE',
          breadcrumb: 'VISUALIZZA_MODELLO',
          preTitle: 'VISUALIZZA_MODELLO',
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'dettaglio-ditta',
            data: {
              title: 'RICERCA_PAT',
              breadcrumb: 'RICERCA_PAT',
              preTitle: 'VISUALIZZA_MODELLO'
            },
            children: [
              {
                path: 'dettaglio-quadro',
                data: {
                  title: 'DETTAGLIO_MODELLO',
                  breadcrumb: 'VISUALIZZA_MODELLO',
                  preTitle: 'VISUALIZZA_MODELLO'
                },
                component: DettaglioQuadroComponent
              },
              {
                path: '',
                data: {
                  title: 'RICERCA_PAT',
                  breadcrumb: '',
                  preTitle: 'VISUALIZZA_MODELLO'
                },
                component: DettaglioDittaComponent,
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: '',
            data: {
              title: 'DELEGHE',
              breadcrumb: '',
              preTitle: 'VISUALIZZA_MODELLO'
            },
            component: DelegheComponent
          },
        ]
      },
    ])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

I want this behavior:

When I open project I want to routing in home page.
When I click on Menu Visualizza Modello, I want to go on this page.
When I click Home on breadcrumb I want to go back in home page.

This works but sometimes when I leave the page and come back only a blank page will appear, not home page.

Can you share with me any idea, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why do you have 2 default `''` routes in your configuration?

Comment: I  think the strange behavior occurs because you have defined the same route for two different things on app-routing-module.ts.
You need to add different path name for
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './visualizza-modello/modello.module#ModelloModule',
    canActivateChild: []
  },

Comment: @MikeS. because it doesn't work for me otherwise. @etaskin I have tried it too  `{ path: 'visualizza-modello', loadChildren: './visualizza-modello/modello.module#ModelloModule', canActivateChild: []}, ` but didn't work

Comment: Well, as @etaskin has already mentioned, having the same path for 2 different routes is likely to produce some strange behavior. Can you reproduce your issue over on [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)? It will be easier to see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are likely right - you can't have two `''` paths.

If you have things set up, then your app-level routing will look similar to this:

`app-routing-module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = {
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMath: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home', component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'visualizza-modello', loadChildren: './visualizza-modello/modello.module#ModelloModule'
    },    
    {
        path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent
    },
};
```

And that's it for your top-level routes. Any pages you want to show in your top, app component `<router-outlet>` will need to be added to this list, just like the `visualizza-modello`.

Inside your `ModelloModule`, you have the routes for this branch of routing. How you do it depends on whether or not your 'new' top level component has a `router-outlet` or not.

Either it's just a collection of pages to display within the main app `router-outlet` and you're essentially just defining a new branch of paths that will be displayed in that top-level router:

`modello-visualizza-routting.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = {
    {
        path: '', component: VisualizzaComponent // this is already url.com/visualizza-modello at this point
    },
    {
        path: 'dettaglio-ditta', component: DettaglioDittaComponent // url.com/visualizza-modello/dettaglio-ditta
    },    
    {
        path: 'dettaglio-quadro', component: DettaglioQuatroComponent // url.com/visualizza-modello/dettaglio-quadro
    },    
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Or your main VisalizzaComponent is just a shell component that has its own `router-outlet`; then you're in the world of child paths.

It's not really that different, you just put those same paths inside `children`. Same urls, but the children will be rendered inside the new `router-outlet` instead of the main app one.

`modello-visualizza-routting.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = {
    {
        path: '',
        component: VisualizzaComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '', component: WhateverHomeComponent
            }
            {
                path: 'dettaglio-ditta', component: DettaglioDittaComponent // url.com/visualizza-modello/dettaglio-ditta
            },    
            {
                path: 'dettaglio-quadro', component: DettaglioQuatroComponent // url.com/visualizza-modello/dettaglio-quadro
            },    
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
};
```